# There are at least as many conjugacy classes in $G$ as in $G/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, quotient-group

> Let $G$ be a finite group with normal subgroup $N$. Show that there are at least
> as many conjugacy classes in $G$ as in $G/N$.

If $a\in G$, then the conjugacy class of $a$ is the set $\{g^{-1}ag:g\in G\}$. I know that if $g_1^{-1}ag_1=g_2^{-1}ag_2$, then $g_2 g_1^{-1}\in C(a)$ (where $C(a)$ is the centralizer of $a$). In other words, $ g_1^{-1}ag_1=g_2^{-1}ag_2$ if $C(a)g_1=C(a)g_2$. Thus the number of elements in the conjugacy class of $a$ is $[G:C(a)]=\frac{|G|}{|C(a)|}$. I think that this fact would help me to answer this exercise, since it relates cosets (the possible elements of $G/N$) with the elements in the conjugacy class of $a$. I have tried to do this in various ways, but so far I have not succeeded. Can you help me please?

---

**Editing (proof writing verification)**

Let $C_G$ be the set of conjugacy classes of $G$ and let $C_{G/N}$ be the set of conjugacy classes of $G/N$. Define $\alpha: C_G \rightarrow C_{G/N}$ via $\alpha (C_a)=C_{aN}$.

> $C_a=\{g^{-1}ag:g\in G\}, C_{aN}=\{g^{-1}NaNgN:gN\in G/N\}=\{g^{-1}agN:gN\in G/N\}$.

If $C_a\neq C_b$, then

$$ \alpha(C_a C_b)=\alpha(C_{ab})=C_{abN}=C_{aNbN}=C_{aN}C_{bN}= \alpha(C_a )\alpha( C_b)$$

thus $\alpha$ is a homomorphism. It is immediately that $\alpha$ is onto. Also, $\text{Ker}(\alpha)=N$, so if $N=\{e\}$, then $\alpha$ is one-to-one and $G$ and $G/N$ has the same number of conjugacy clases. Otherwise, $G$ has at least as many conjugacy classes as in $G/N$.

Is the proof correct? Could you change some of the notation or is it okay?

Comment: Can you think of a way to turn a conjugacy class of $G$ into a conjugacy class of $G/N$? Do you see why the resulting map $\{\text{conjugacy classes of $G$}\}\rightarrow\{\text{conjugacy classes of $G/N$}\}$ is surjective?

Comment: If $g$ and $g'$ are conjugate in $G$, then their classes are conjugate in $G/N$, but they may also be *the same* class. Does this give you an idea of what happens?

Comment: @Thorgott I think I understand. Let $C_G$ be the set of conjugacy classes of $G$ and let $C_{G/N}$ be the set of conjugacy classes of $G/N$. I define $\alpha:C_G→C_{G/N}$ via $\alpha(g^{−1}ag)=g^{−1}agN$. Clearly $\alpha$ is a surjective homomorphism. Also, It is not one-to-one if $N\neq\{e\}$, since if $g^{−1}ag\in \text{Ker}(\alpha)$ then $g^{−1}agN=eN$; that is, all $g^{−1}ag\in N$. Am I right?

Comment: $g^{-1}ag$ is an element of $G$, not a conjugacy class. You mean the right thing, but you're not writing precisely.

Comment: @Thorgott I understand what you mean, but I can't think of how I could correct it. Could you give me any suggestions please?

Comment: @Thorgott If $C_a=\{g^{-1}ag:g\in G\}$, $\alpha(C_a)=C_{aN}$ works?

Comment: Your notation is a bit ambiguous ($C_a$ is a subset of $G$, but $C_{aN}$ is a subset of $G/N$), but you absolutely mean the right thing: the conjugacy class of $a$ in $G$ gets mapped to the conjugacy class of $aN$ in $G/N$. Of course, you have to argue this is well-defined.